# How to SELECT INTO <a calculated table name>?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query that will select data from one table INTO a new table, with the new table's name using a combination of 'NewTable' and the getdate() function.

```
Select * Into 'NewTable' + FORMAT(getdate(),'yyyy')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: A SQL query is compiled, it cannot change at *runtime* or rely on runtime calculated values.

Comment: Whenever I see a table name that includes the date it is immediately known that the design went way off target.